# Ruby mongo: unable to increment integer field using atomic operations

Tags: ruby, mongodb, syntax

I am unable to run a command the increment a integer counter in mongo DB. The command though works in mongo shell just fine.

So here the sample program:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'

# create sample mongo local DB
db = Mongo::Connection.new.db("dbtest")

# create sample mongo collection within DB
mytable = db.collection("tabletest")

# inserting some records into sample collection
mytable.insert({'name'=>'apple','mycnt'=>0})
mytable.insert({'name'=>'orange','mycnt'=>0})
mytable.insert({'name'=>'pear','mycnt'=>0})

######## following statement throws error
######syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting $end
mytable.update({"name": "apple"},{"$inc": {"mycnt": 1}})
```

I am not sure what is wrong in the last statement in terms of syntax when running as normal ruby program (not mongo shell). Any help is greatly appreciated. Similar command in mongo shell works fine, which looks like following:

```
# db.tabletest.update({name: "apple"},{$inc: {mycnt: 1}})
```

Answer (score 4):

The new style JSONish Hash syntax only works with symbols as the keys, you're trying to use it with strings. Also, the `$inc:` will be seen as the global variable `$inc` followed by a colon so you can't use the JSONish syntax when you want to use the `:$inc` symbol as a key. Use the hashrocket syntax instead:

```
mytable.update({:name => "apple"},{:$inc => {:mycnt => 1}})
mytable.update({'name' => "apple"},{'$inc' => {'mycnt' => 1}})
```